When discharging a capacitor, why would a resistor make a difference if it is situated after ground?
So I am currently analyzing RC circuits in my textbook, and, just out of curiosity, I conjured up this circuit on Multisim to charge and discharge a capacitor using a SPDT switch.  This first circuit (see below) makes sense to me: at t=0, the voltage at the left plate of the capacitor is 12 V and the voltage at ground is always zero, so the current immediately flows from the left side of the capacitor (which has a positive charge) to ground, and so the voltage across the capacitor drops to zero instantaneously.

Now if I fully recharge the capacitor and this time open switch S2 so that R2 is no longer shorted before flipping up switch S2 (again calling that moment t = 0), I would expect the same result, since the voltage at t = 0 on the left plate of the capacitor is again 12 V and the voltage at ground is again always zero, and the ground is located BEFORE the resistor R2 (with respect to the direction of the current which I measured to be correct using an ammeter) so the current should (at least as far as I understand) go from the left plate straight to ground and therefore cause the voltage across the capacitor to instantaneously drop to zero like it did above.  But this is not the case.  The voltage, according to the oscilloscope shown at the bottom, appears to drop exponentially, NOT instantaneously, as if the current (drawn in as purple) was somehow affected by R2.  I do not see why the current should be affected by R2 since it comes after ground.  So what am I missing?


Please take a screenshot next time, instead of taking a photo of your screen.

Two concepts that you are missing: "ground" is arbitrary and voltage is relative. And one more: current flows in loops.
In the first example, R2 is shorted by SW1. This also shorts the capacitors right plate to ground. You flip SW1 up. this shorts the capacitor and it discharges to zero instantly. All is well. (TBH, I'm surprised that works so well in the simulator. But that's a separate issue. The important thing for now is that it "works").
In your next case, you have a fully charged capacitor with SW2 open. The only discharge path of current in this case is through R2 - the capacitor's right plate is no longer grounded - it is sitting on R2. In other words it is not ground-referenced. So your assumption is wrong:

I would expect the same result, since the voltage at t = 0 on the left plate of the capacitor is again 12 V and the voltage at ground is again always zero, and the ground is located BEFORE the resistor R2 (with respect to the direction of the current which I measured to be correct using an ammeter) so the current should (at least as far as I understand) go from the left plate straight to ground and therefore cause the voltage across the capacitor to instantaneously drop to zero like it did above.

The current still has to discharge through the resistor which gives rise to your first-order response (the decay after t=0). So everything you are seeing is exactly as what is expected. What might be making this hard to understand is the way your circuit is constructed, the capacitor is not ground referenced and you are making a differential voltage measurement with the floating volt meter. Normally, when you are learning electronics, you want the components to be ground referenced so all measurements are taking WRT ground for clarity and convivence. You capacitor is "riding" on top of the resistor in the second example.
Here's your circuit re-drawn "properly" (my way):

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
This should make it easier to understand.

Ah. So basically, there is a potential across the capacitor at t = 0 equal to 12 V no matter what you call ground thus causing a current to flow in a loop, including R2.  So, keeping just about everything in my circuit the same, if I were to put the ground on the left side of R2, thereby connecting the right side of the capacitor to ground, this would be the "Academic" Analysis Way you described?

@polimorphism Not exactly. That would actually change the circuit.  A better way to understand this is to use "my circuit" on the left in my answer and move the ground symbol to anywhere and rerun the simulation. The way I've shown it, it is topologically equivalent to your circuit. What you're suggesting changes the circuit - you ground is "split". So to do it your way, add a wire between between both of your ground symbols. Delete one of them. Now you can put the "ground" anywhere you want - splitting a node changes the circuit.

@polimorphism I'm partially wrong and you're right but only by coincidence. Moving the ground where you want to put it will change the charging behavior while SW2 is open.  The charging behavior is is identical when SW1 is closed whether you leave the ground in the original location or in your new proposed location. The reason you are right is because the SW1 breaks the loop so the battery, R1, and its ground is vestigial during the discharge. In other words SW1 gives you a separate loop. That's why what you are doing works. Didn't realize that from your crazy schematic ;-) till I drew it out.

Sorry, I deleted my comment because I realized that moving the ground to the left of R2 doesn't affect the discharging behavior but DOES actually change the charging behavior by a significant amount since the current isn't forced to go through R2 to get to ground, thus effectively doubling the time constant.  For the record, I appreciate your much cleaner schematic.  Gotta work on that over here! XD

+1 for redrawing. Electrical networks may become clearer when you redraw them in a common way, e.g. everything grounded at the bottom, etc.

Current flows in loops. The discharge loop in the second case is across R2. So the voltage of the capacitor will exponentially decay with the given RC time constant.
You mix into your thoughts that the left pin of the capacitor is switched to ground and ground is always 0V. Keep in mind that your oscilloscope is not measuring a voltage with ground reference. If you measure the left pin with reference to ground, the voltage will be zero at switching time t=0. This however does not instantaneously discharge the capacitor.

"If you measure the left pin with reference to ground, the voltage will be zero at switching time t=0."  So does that mean, keeping everything the same, at t = 0, the voltage on the right pin would be -12 V ?

Yes, that should be correct. Feel free to test it.

You assume the scope ground is same as circuit ground.
Assume they are are not, like the breadboard being powered by a battery, and the oscilloscope too, so they do not share any other ground reference between them, except the scope negative lead which you can connect as you wish to provide a reference.
Just like a battery operated multimeter with two leads. It cannot measure any absolute potential, it can only measure the potential difference between the two leads.
And so your circuit discharges the cap through resistance so the capacitor voltage waveform will be an exponential RC doscharge waveform.
It might be better seen from the circuit if you remove the wires from scope. Charging via 0R short circuit, dischargin via resistor.

There are a couple of subtle, yet, very important concepts you are missing:

Components are in series (directly or indirectly) or in parallel (both components are between the same nodes) to other components. There is no "before" or "after" in a circuit diagram such as this, the length or order of components on a "wire" do not matter. They are merely an abstraction of a node.

Current must always follow a closed loop. The ground indication is an abstraction indicating a given node is your reference for electrical potential (i.e. voltage) and also that it is an infinite supply of electrical charge, enabling current loops to be closed through them. This means that if you have multiple grounds, it is the same as connecting the respective locations with "wires".


Considering these points, connect the wires on two grounds with another wire (and consider removing one of them), it will help to better visualize that when you open S1 and:

When S2 is closed, you are connecting both poles of the capacitor (and also of the oscilloscope) to the same node/"wire", so in short, an electrical short and there should be no difference in electrical potential between them (i.e. voltage).
When S2 is open, you are connecting the capacitor (and oscilloscope) to the poles of resistor R2. The exponential shape is due to the math behind this circuit. You can look up First Order Circuit to better understand this (requires higher level math, such as Calculus and Differential Equations).

Considering studying Kirchhoff's circuit laws to better understand the two points of the answer.

All the answers up to the point of my reading are definitely right, and go to inform solid circuit understanding. I think the biggest point to your intuitive understanding is realizing how your oscilloscope is connected -- only across the plates of the capacitor.
I'd be willing to bet if you were to have your scope probing the "left" side, i.e. what is initially charged to +12V (with respect to ground), putting the 'negative' lead on ground you'd see an identical plot to scenario 1 (where you have S2 closed).
I'd also be willing to bet that the "right" terminal of the capacitor in scenario 2 drops immediately to -12V with respect to ground when you toggle S1 then climbs up towards 0V perfectly mirroring the exponential decay you see on your plot.
The key takeaway here is that the voltage across a capacitor does not instantly change (it might look that way in your sim, but in reality that'd just be an incredibly short time duration decay - resulting in a blown capacitor). One can actually be pretty creative in how they switch capacitors in and out of circuits to boost voltages (see voltage doublers, high side N-MOSFET gate drivers, etc.) using the exact thing you're seeing in your question.

From reading these answers, I think the main wrong assumption I made is that, calling ground to be zero volts, the voltage on the left plate of the capacitor is +12 V at t = 0. Since the left plate is connected straight to ground, at t = 0 it would also be equal to 0 volts, making the voltage on the right plate to be negative 12 V wrt ground. This difference in potential would thereby cause a current to flow through R2, since that is the only path for the charge on the right plate to get to ground, or if you wanted to be technical, it is the only path for the positive charge at ground to get to a lower potential at the right plate (since current always flows from higher potential to lower).
